# how pass data from view to controller (use jquery post)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i want when user click on button value of Select tag pass to action controller

```
 <select id="TypeID" style="font-size: x-small">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">--- select---</option>
            <option value="1">حقیقی (اشخاص)</option>
            <option value="2">حقوقی (شرکت)</option>
            <option value="3">دولتی (سازمان)</option>
            <option value="4">فروشگاه </option>
        </select>
```

i use jquery post :

```
 function PassType() {
         var formData = $("#TypeID").val();
         alert(formData);



         $.post("/Customer/Create", formData, function (data) {
            alert(data.toString());
        }, "text");
     };
```

but pass null to action

Answer (score 0):

This is the article you need to read - posting JSON to MVC action:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Comment: no i I do not json .i want pass only value select (i want use text)

Comment: Pass the selected text as JSON, ie: `{ text: $("#TypeID").val() }`

Comment: What do you mean by 'return null'? is the argument in your action `null`? Have you followed all the steps from the article? Have you names the argument properly? - don't get me wrong, but posting JSON to MVC action works. Verify in Fiddler that you're actually POSTing correct data.